# Cannot access dual boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, kali

I am running umbuntu 16.04, I partitioned the hard drive and installed kali Linux. During boot up there is no way to choose to boot up with kali. It auto defaults to umbuntu. I was told to use the gksu gedit /etc/default/grub and then delete a certain line. I don't know if that will work and I don't want to edit something that could mess everything else up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am Sure that You have the same problem as me 
"Problem with GRUB"
GRUB2 is what is reqiured for the prompt at boot time .
I do not know how to fix it but you can pursue it to get a better responseto repair your computer

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal window and update grub.

You can do this by typing `terminal` in the Ubuntu search button.  Then run `Terminal`.

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

The Grub diskmanager will search all your installed drives and install add all detected Operating systems to the menu.